# puppet --version fails with ruby issue

Tags: ruby, centos, puppet, centos6

I have CentOS6 on which I have configured puppet server. but Whenever I try to execute ant puppet command it fails with ruby issue. see the output for `puppet --version`

```
-bash-4.1# puppet --version
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Tried re-installing puppet and ruby but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Try I had a similar issue, and did a few things and it was fixed before I knew which one fixed it, but try this:

```
gem update --system
yum install ruby-json
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your Ruby `1.8.7` is trying to use a `1.9.3` gem for some reason.

This can be tricky to get right. In your shoes, I would check if I can

- get rid of `ruby1.8` altogether
- make `ruby1.9` the default Ruby on the system
- make sure that Puppet always uses `ruby1.9`

Specifics depend heavily on the way Ruby and Puppet were actually installed.

Comment: I'd suggest the other way around.  Ruby 1.8.7 is the default packaged Ruby on CentOS 6, removing it may cause all sorts of packages to fail.  1.9 has been installed under RVM, so either remove that or use `rvm use system` to temporarily disable it.

Comment: Don't use ruby 1.9.3 unless you really, really know what you're doing. All rubygems installed with yum will go to the default ruby (1.8.7)

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91listen to the CentOS folks. I was thinking from a Debianish angle, where you had some more freedoms (until jessie). Ruby `1.8.7` is horrible, but sticking to it is sensible in an environment that is tailored towards that (i.e. your CentOS system).